# How to solve the problem of Promise { <pending> }?

Tags: node.js, koa2

Here is my code:

```
router.get("test", async ctx => {
  let q = await ctx.db
    .execute(`SELECT w.create_time as create_time,w.camera_id,w.status,
  w.problem_type_id,w.repair_user_id,w.no as no,wp.pic_url
  FROM work_flow w
  left OUTER
  JOIN work_flow_pic wp ON w.no=wp.flow_id`);
  let data = q.map(item => {
    let url = ctx.db.execute(
      `select * from work_flow_pic where flow_id=${item.no}`
    );
    return {
      create_time: item.create_time,
      no: item.no,
      url: url.then(function(result) {
        result;
      })
    };
  });
  console.log(data);
  let retstr = `[{"ret":"0"}]`;
  await ctx.render("interface_ret", {
    retstr
  });
});
```

When I run the code I get this output:

```
    [ { create_time: 2018-10-09T02:47:54.000Z,
    no: '153905327352986',
    url: Promise { <pending> } },
  { create_time: 2018-10-09T02:47:54.000Z,
    no: '153905327352986',
    url: Promise { <pending> } },
  { create_time: 2018-10-09T08:51:33.000Z,
    no: '153905327352987',
    url: Promise { <pending> } } ]
```

I don't know how to solve it

Answer (score 1):

When you want to wait for a promise to resolve and get it's return value you can use `await` as you did above:

```
let q = await ctx.db.execute(`SELECT w.create_time as 
     create_time,w.camera_id,w.status,
     w.problem_type_id,w.repair_user_id,w.no as no,wp.pic_url
     FROM work_flow w left OUTER JOIN work_flow_pic wp ON w.no=wp.flow_id`);//get q from table
let data = q.map(item => {
let url = await ctx.db.execute(`select * from work_flow_pic where 
flow_id=${item.no}`); //get url from q
return {
  create_time: item.create_time,
  no: item.no,
  url: url
  })
}
});
  console.log(data);
```

Comment: thanks I tried your method,but it still got an error like this "let url = await ctx.db.execute(`select * from work_flow_pic where
              ^^^^^

SyntaxError: await is only valid in async function
"

Comment: You have to be in an async environment. As you did before.

Comment: how to write the async environment before await?

Comment: It's in your question now: `router.get("test", async ctx => {`...});` but any function with the prefix async would work

Comment: you mean that i can not use async again? because I have used router.get("test", async ctx => {...}) already

Comment: I change the code like this but I still not get what i want

Comment: let url = async function(){ await ctx.db.execute(`select * from work_flow_pic where flow_id=${item.no}`); }; I change the code like this but still not work

Comment: What I meant is that you already were in an async environment

Comment: You need to convert your map function to an async one

Comment: fine,I will try

Answer (score 0):

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9IrAz.jpg)

I finally figure out the problem.

Answer (score 0):

```
let ps = q.map(async item => {
  let url = await ctx.db.execute(
    `select * from work_flow_pic where flow_id=${item.no}`
  );
  return {
    create_time: item.create_time,
    no: item.no,
    url: url
  };
});

const data = await Promise.all(ps);
```

use map to make promise array, wait all done => all data(array)